# splice not working on array of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm creating a bubbles effect, but I have an issue removing a bubble when it reaches the top. The bubbles are circle `svg` elements and are stored in an array. The splice function returns an error. You can see it in the `animateBubbles()` function. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'splice'

```
let bubbles = [];

let bubblesC = [];

function createBubbles(n, x, y, w, h) {

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        let circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');

        bubblesC[i] = Math.PI / (Math.random() * Math.floor(10));

        let tmpX =  x + getRandomInt(w);

        circle.setAttribute('cx', tmpX);
        circle.setAttribute('cy', getRandomInt(h)+wHeight);
        circle.setAttribute('r', 3+getRandomInt(10));

        circle.setAttribute("id", "bubble" + i);
        circle.setAttribute("fill", "url(#grad3)");
        circle.setAttribute("stroke", "light");
        circle.setAttribute("opacity", "0.5");

        bubbles.push(circle);

        svg.appendChild(circle);

    }

}

function animateBubbles() {

    for (let i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {

        let bx = parseInt(bubbles[i].getAttribute("cx"));
        let by = parseInt(bubbles[i].getAttribute("cy"));

        bx += Math.round(2 * Math.sin(bubblesC[i]));
        by += -2;

        if (by < wavesY) {
            bubbles[i].setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
            bubbles[i].setAttribute("stroke", "white");
        }

        if (by < wavesY - 20) {
            //by = getRandomInt(wHeight)+wHeight;
            bubbles[i].setAttribute("fill", "url(#grad3)");
            bubbles[i].setAttribute("stroke", "light");
            bubbles[i].setAttribute("opacity", "0.5");
        }

        if (by < wavesY - 40) {

            bubbles[i].splice(i, 1); ////////////////// THIS IS THE PROBLEM

            //bubbles[i].parentNode.removeChild(bubbles[i]);

        }

        bubbles[i].setAttribute("cx", bx);
        bubbles[i].setAttribute("cy", by);

        bubblesC[i] += Math.PI / 8;

    }

}
```

Comment: bubbles[i] is an object, not an array. try using `delete bubbles[i]`

Comment: Should be `bubbles.splice(i, 1)`. `splice` belongs to array not to an element.

Comment: Also you are mutating an array while iterating over it. Your index `i` becomes invalid. You'll need to either restore it's value manually or iterate in reverse order. Or a better option would be not too mutate the array in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

`splice` can only be used on an array not on an object. Use `bubbles.splice(i, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

`Array.splice()` remove a given number of elements starting at a given index and all the remaining elements shift down. Then the afterthought block of the for-loop increments `i` by 1. So that a index is skipped.

Take a look at:

```
let fiboArray  = [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ];

// Array.splice() fails in forward for loops
for (let i = 0; i <= fiboArray.length ; i++) {
    if (fiboArray[i] === 1) {
        fiboArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log(fiboArray); // → [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ]
```

A backward for-loop can handle this special behavior

```
let fiboArray  = [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ];

// Array.splice() with backward for loops
for (let i = fiboArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (fiboArray[i] === 1) {
        fiboArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log(fiboArray); // → [ 2, 3, 5, 8 ]
```

But as answered before: `splice()` can only be used on an `Array`

change

```
bubbles[i].splice(i, 1);
```

to

```
bubbles.splice(i, 1);
```